# Converting a S3 data folder into bucketed and partitioned data store

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a folder with TBs of structured data and they all adher to a fixed schema. The folder structure is as such:

```
s3://main-bucket/
                folder-1/ <= One folder will only contain data from one algorithm
                                part-0000-1.csv <= Created on 06/01/2019 by algorithm1
                                part-0000-2.csv <= Created on 06/01/2019 by algorithm1
                folder-2/
                                part-1000-1.csv <= Created on 06/02/2019 by algorithm2
                                part-1000-2.csv <= Created on 06/02/2019 by algorithm2
```

Querying on main-bucket using Spark or Athena is very inefficient and I wanted to convert it a format like this:

```
s3://data-bucket/
                algorithm1/ <= derived from a column in folder-1/part files and all rows in this folder has the same algorithm value
                  2019/                   
                    06/
                      01/
                        part-0001.parquet
                algorithm2/
                    2019/                   
                       06/
                         02/
                            part-0001.parquet
```

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, there is a field within your data files that contains the date elements or at least a date field.

Partitioning folders typically include the name of the field, such as:

```
algorithm1/year=2019/month=06/day=01/part-0001.parquet
```

This way, Athena can "know" what is in each directory by merely scanning the path names.

The easiest way to convert this format is with Athena itself. Basically:

- Define an **input table** that describes and points to the existing data
- Define an **output table** configured as Parquet, defining fields to use for partitions
- Select data out of the input table into the output table

See: [Converting to Columnar Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the problem there is no field within my data files that contains the date. The only timestamp that I can use is the one on the s3 file.

Comment: If each data file belongs to a specific day, then you could **move the files** into a hierarchy like `algorithm1/year=2019/month=06/day=01/part-0001.parquet` or even `algorithm1/date=2019-06-01/part-0001.parquet`. This will allow Athena to create date fields based on the folder name. It works quite well.

Comment: The problem is that it is 7.7 TB of data and moving all those files in S3 with a single script or program will take forever because in S3 there is no renaming. All these files will have to be moved. The only way to do this would be with some tool like AWS Glue or Spark

Comment: You will need to process all the data anyway, since you wish to convert from CSV to Parquet. Once you have moved the historical data, each new day's worth of data will be quite small. Or, if you merely wish to move the data without processing it, then you could write a script that uses `aws s3 mv` — behind the scenes, it will actually do a copy and a delete.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not have a date field in your data, you'll not be able to create that partitions only using Spark.

One possible solution consists of listing all the CSV files from the S3 bucket and collect the metadata: `creation/modification time` and `owner`. For this, you could use Hadoop filesystem API. Something like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val path = new Path("s3://main-bucket/")
val fs = path.getFileSystem(spark.sessionState.newHadoopConf)
val files = fs.listStatus(path)

val filesMeta = files.map{f => (f.getPath().toString, f.getModificationTime(), f.getOwner())}
```

For a recursive listing, you can use [`listFiles`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listFiles(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean)) instead.

With that list, you can create a DataFrame with columns: `file_path, timestamp, owner` that you can join with DataFrame you get from all the data using the column `input_file_name()` and add columns `timestamp` and `creator` with some formatting for the date.

Now you have the column creator and date, so you can write parquet and partition by those 2 columns to get the structure you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you data files have datetime incorporated in their names you can utilise a "secret" variable `$PATH` within an Athena query. Then you can utilise `regexp_extract` and [datetime functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) to create columns which then can be used within CTAS query to partition your data.

Here is the structure of mock files in my S3:

```
s3://main-bucket/questions=59541533
├── folder-1
|    ├── file1-2019-01-01.json
|    ├── file1-2019-01-02.json
|    ├── file1-2019-02-01.json
|    └── file1-2019-02-02.json
├── folder-2
|    ├── file1-2019-01-01.json
|    ├── file1-2019-01-02.json
|    ├── file1-2019-02-01.json
|    └──  file1-2019-02-02.json
```

Then I defined a table that points to `folder-1`:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `stackoverflow`.`question_59541533_v1`(
  `foo` int,
  `bar` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'paths'='row,uf')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://main-bucket/questions=59541533/folder-1'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='json',
  'compressionType'='none'
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Here is how query can look like where I extract date from the file name with quite naive [`regexp_extract`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html) since file names are deterministic.

```sql
SELECT
    YEAR("file_date") as "year",
    MONTH("file_date") as "month",  
    DAY("file_date") as "day"
FROM(
    SELECT
        DATE(regexp_extract("$PATH", '(.)*/(.)*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).json', 3)) as "file_date",
    FROM
        "stackoverflow"."question_59541533_v1"
)
ORDER BY month, day
```

Result:

```
year  | month | day
---------------------
2019  | 1     | 1
2019  | 1     | 2
2019  | 2     | 1
2019  | 2     | 2
```

Now, you can convert data and partition it in one go with CTAS query (don't forget to select all your original data)

```sql
CREATE TABLE partitioned_and_in_parquet
WITH (
    format = 'PARQUET',
    external_location = 's3://new_s3_location/',
    partitioned_by = ARRAY['year', 'month', 'day']
) AS (
    SELECT
        * , -- select existing data
        YEAR("file_date") as "year",
        MONTH("file_date") as "month",  
        DAY("file_date") as "day"
    FROM(
        SELECT
            * ,  -- select existing data
            DATE(regexp_extract("$PATH", '(.)*/(.)*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).json', 3)) as "file_date",
        FROM
            "stackoverflow"."question_59541533_v1"
    )    
)
```

Advantage of this approach is that you partition data and convert it to parquet in one go. On top of that you would know in advance how much you would get charged, since Athena pricing is based on the amount of data being scanned, i.e. 1TB = 5$.

One the main downside of this approach is CTAS query has a limitation of writing of only 100 partitions at a time. So if you have more then 3 month of data query would fail, unless you add `WHERE` clause to overcome this. You can you `$PATH` in `WHERE` clause. I remember that I tested it some time ago and even when files would be in the same "folder" Athena wouldn't scan content of the files, hence, you won't be charged multiple times. But I'd suggest to verify this.
Alternatively, just stop at months level.

Other thing that you would need to consider is the number of output files of CTAS query and their sizes. In general, you can use [bucketing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/bucketing-vs-partitioning.html), i.e. `bucketed_by = ARRAY['some_column'], bucket_count = 3`, to control it, but it might increase run time.

Anyway, there are a lot of things to play with if you decide to do this with Athena.